# Как преобразовать IntStream в List<Integer>?

Tags: java, list, коллекции, потоки-данных, java-stream

Почему в первом случае при попытке преобразовать стрим в лист - ошибка компиляции, а во втором - все ок? По сути, ведь идентичные действия?

```java
public class Test1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Вариант 1
        int[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
        List<Integer> integerList = Arrays.stream(array)
                .filter(s -> s % 2 == 0)
                .collect(Collectors.toList()); // compile error

        // Вариант 2
        List<String> stringList = Arrays.stream(args)
                .filter(s -> s.length() <= 2)
                .collect(Collectors.toList()); // ok
    }
}
```

Comment: Текст ошибки добавьте в вопрос.

Comment: Скорее всего потому, что int - премитивный тип, а Integer и String - нет

Comment: Текст ошибки: Expected 3 arguments bun found 1.

Comment: Если вы получили исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый (плюсик и галочка слева от ответа)

Answer (score 2):

Проблема заключается в том, что `int` - примитивный тип, поэтому в первом случае у вас используется не стандартный `Stream`, а `IntStream`, который является последовательностью примитивных целочисленных значений. Так как вы не можете создать список, хранящий примитивы, необходимо их превратить в их объектную оболочку (т.е `int` -> `Integer`). Для этого используйте метод `boxed()`:

```
List<Integer> integerList = Arrays.stream(array)
        .filter(s -> s % 2 == 0)
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Метод [`Arrays.stream(int[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-int:A-) возвращает [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html), который затем можно преобразовать.

1. Получаем массив `int[]` с помощью метода [`toArray`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#toArray--):

   ```java
   int[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

   int[] array2 =
           // получаем IntStream
           // по массиву int[]
           Arrays.stream(array)
                   // отбираем четные числа
                   .filter(s -> s % 2 == 0)
                   // преобразовываем
                   // в массив int[]
                   .toArray();

   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array2)); // [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
   ```
2. Получаем `Stream<Integer>` с помощью метода [`boxed`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#boxed--) и далее собираем в `List<Integer>`:

   ```java
   int[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

   List<Integer> integerList =
           // получаем IntStream
           // по массиву int[]
           Arrays.stream(array)
                   // отбираем четные числа
                   .filter(s -> s % 2 == 0)
                   // преобразовываем
                   // в Stream<Integer>
                   .boxed()
                   // собираем в лист
                   .collect(Collectors.toList());

   System.out.println(integerList); // [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
   ```

---

См. [`Как преобразовать строку в List<Long>?`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1212791/419011)