# Как преобразовать строку в List<Long>? Выдает ошибку: Cannot resolve method 'parseLong'

Tags: java, java-stream

Не могу понять, из-за чего ошибка. Код не работает:

```java
String number = "1,2,3";
List<Long> listNums = Stream.of(number)
        .map(i -> i.split(","))
        .mapToLong(Long::parseLong) // Cannot resolve method 'parseLong'
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Может сразу

```
String number = "1,2,3";
List<Long> listNums =
    Arrays.asList(number.split(",")).stream()
        .map(item -> Long.parseLong(item))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

Добавил комментарии для наглядности:

```java
String number = "1,2,3";
List<Long> list = Stream.of(number)
        // разбиваем строку на массив,
        // получаем Stream<String[]>
        .map(i -> i.split(","))
        // разбираем элементы массивов String[]
        // получаем общий Stream<String>
        .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
        // разбираем из строки число,
        // получаем LongStream
        .mapToLong(Long::parseLong)
        // преобразовываем LongStream в Stream<Long>,
        // чтобы можно было собрать в лист
        .boxed()
        // собираем в лист
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(list); // [1, 2, 3]
```

---

Начиная с `9` версии Java появился метод [`String.chars`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#chars--):

```java
String number = "1,2,3";
List<Long> list = number
        // получаем IntStream
        // по символам строки
        .chars()
        // только цифры
        .filter(Character::isDigit)
        // символ в виде строки
        .mapToObj(Character::toString)
        // строка в виде числа
        .mapToLong(Long::parseLong)
        // LongStream в Stream<Long>
        .boxed()
        // собираем в лист
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(list); // [1, 2, 3]
```

---

См. [`Как преобразовать IntStream в List<Integer>?`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1214146/419011)